# Puppet tries to rename sites-avaialbe folder

Tags: puppet

I am running Puppet on staging server, for some reasons puppet starts trying removing sites-available folder and I have no idea why. Any hint will be helpful.

```
Error: Could not set 'file' on ensure: Is a directory @ rb_file_s_rename - (/etc/nginx/sites-available20180808-12536-11p54v, /etc/nginx/sites-available) at 12:/etc/puppet/modules/nginx/manifests/vhost.pp
Error: Could not set 'file' on ensure: Is a directory @ rb_file_s_rename - (/etc/nginx/sites-available20180808-12536-11p54v, /etc/nginx/sites-available) at 12:/etc/puppet/modules/nginx/manifests/vhost.pp
```

Code:

```
define nginx::vhost($docroot, $port = 80, $template = 'nginx/vhost_php.erb', $allow = [], $deny = [], $aliases = [])
    {
      include nginx

      file { "/etc/nginx/sites-available/${name}":
        owner   => 'root',
        group   => 'root',
        mode    => 644,
        content => template($template),
        require => Package['nginx'],
        notify  => Service['nginx'],
      }

      file { "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/${name}":
        ensure  => 'link',
        target  => "/etc/nginx/sites-available/${name}",
        require => File["/etc/nginx/sites-available/${name}"],
        notify  => Service['nginx'],
      }
    }
```

Comment: As you can tell from the error message, you are trying to convert a directory into a file. Puppet will refuse to do that without a `force` attribute since it is dangerous. It is unclear what your true intentions are from this code.

Comment: As a general point, I'd be wary of writing my own `nginx` module for Puppet. Puppet Forge has an official `nginx` module, which has worked fine for me in the past. https://forge.puppet.com/puppet/nginx

Answer (score 1):

As @MattSchuchard remarked in comments, the error messages show that Puppet thinks you've asked it to convert a directory into a file.  Furthermore, it appears to be associating that action with the first `File` resource in your manifest, which declares

```
file { "/etc/nginx/sites-available/${name}":
  # ...
}
```

You will note that that resource appears to be trying to manage a file inside the directory, rather than the directory itself, but that discrepancy would be resolved if the automagic `$name` variable happened to take an empty string as its value.  That's what I presume is happening.

You don't show the relevant declaration(s) of the `nginx::vhost` resources, but I think you'll find that the problem is there.  The (slightly) broader context of those error messages would probably confirm this diagnosis: it normally contains a path-like specification of the resource in which the error occurred, and that would include the relevant resource title.

Comment: Thanks for your time guys, I figured out the reason of this failure. Where system was trying to create sites-available for domain that actually does not exit on staging environment but in production.